# Facebook login with firebase vs FacebookSDK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have question and I searched too much for the answer and didn't found anything,

What is the difference between between integrating firebase login directly with Facebook Developers and FacebookSDK, and integrating with firebase authentication!!
Which features i will gain when integrating with firebase to perform Facebook login.

Hint: 
I have my backend with php(Laravel Framework) and MySQL Database.

Comment: Please don't ask question like "What is the difference between" see documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For integrating Firebase authentication you still need to use Facebook SDK library if you want to be able to have Facebook login. Firebase authentication is basically wrapper of other authentications.